# How to parse JSON of multi-type array using Aeson into a custom Haskell type?

Tags: haskell, aeson

this is my first post on Stack Overflow and I'm very new to Haskell and programming/web development in general. I'm using it to try and parse some JSON into an ADT type.

Here is the section of JSON I want to try and parse:

```
{"resource":"teamgamelog",
 "parameters":{"TeamID":1610612747,"LeagueID":null,"Season":"2015-16","SeasonType":"Regular Season","DateFrom":null,"DateTo":null},
 "resultSets":[
   {"name":"TeamGameLog",
    "headers":["Team_ID","Game_ID","GAME_DATE","MATCHUP","WL","W","L","W_PCT","MIN","FGM","FGA","FG_PCT","FG3M","FG3A","FG3_PCT","FTM","FTA","FT_PCT","OREB","DREB","REB","AST","STL","BLK","TOV","PF","PTS"], 
    "rowSet": [ [1610612747,"0021501228","APR 13, 2016","LAL vs. UTA","W",17,65,0.207,240,41,85,0.482,6,25,0.240,13,15,0.867,8,39,47,19,6,3,13,17,101]
               ,[1610612747,"0021501209","APR 11, 2016","LAL @ OKC","L",16,65,0.198,240,23,81,0.284,7,31,0.226,26,30,0.867,10,38,48,15,8,1,15,20,79]
               ,[1610612747,"0021501195","APR 10, 2016","LAL @ HOU","L",16,64,0.2,240,41,83,0.494,12,28,0.429,16,19,0.842,7,33,40,25,10,3,18,15,110]
               .
               .
               .
               ]
   }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is ending up with `[GameResult]` where each `GameResult` is made from the nested array's in the JSON `"rowSet"` key:

```
data GameResult = GameResult { team_ID   :: Int
                             , game_ID   :: String
                             , game_date :: String
                             , matchup   :: String
                             , wl        :: Char
                             , w         :: Int
                             , l         :: Int
                             , w_pct     :: Float
                             , min       :: Int
                             , fgm       :: Int
                             , fga       :: Int
                             , fg_pct    :: Float
                             , fg3m      :: Int
                             , fg3a      :: Int
                             , fg3_pct   :: Float
                             , ftm       :: Int
                             , fta       :: Int
                             , ft_pct    :: Float
                             , oreb      :: Int
                             , dreb      :: Int
                             , reb       :: Int
                             , ast       :: Int
                             , stl       :: Int
                             , blk       :: Int
                             , tov       :: Int
                             , pf        :: Int
                             , pts       :: Int
                             } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Read)
```

I have this so far:

```
module Main where

import Data.Aeson
import Network.HTTP.Conduit (simpleHttp)

data RowSet  = ResultSet [GameResult] deriving (Show, Eq, Read)
data ResultSets = ResultSets [RowSet] deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

instance FromJSON ResultSets where
  parseJSON (Object o) = ResultSets <$> (o .: "resultSets")

instance FromJSON RowSetSet where
  parseJSON (Object o) = RowSet <$> (o .: "rowSet")

jsonURL :: String
jsonURL = "http://stats.nba.com/stats/teamgamelog/?Season=2015-16&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&TeamID=1610612747"

getJSON :: IO B.ByteString
getJSON = simpleHttp jsonURL

main :: IO ()
main = do
  d <- (eitherDecode <$> getJSON) :: IO (Either String (Maybe ResultSets)) 
  case d of
    Left err -> putStrLn err
    Right ps -> putStrLn (show ps)
```

Not sure if this is exactly the direction I should be going, but I was thinking of a lengthy pattern match:

```
instance FromJSON GameResult where
  parseJSON arr = do 
  [a,b,c,...x,y,z] <- parseJSON arr
  GameResult <$> a <*> b <*> c <*> ...
```

Of course I'm getting a number of errors trying to compile:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Float’
  Expected type: Parser Float
    Actual type: Parser Int
In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘l’
  In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
    ‘GameResult <$> a <*> b <*> c <*> d <*> e <*> f <*> g <*> h <*> i
     <*> j
     <*> k
     <*> l’
  In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
    ‘GameResult <$> a <*> b <*> c <*> d <*> e <*> f <*> g <*> h <*> i
     <*> j
     <*> k
     <*> l
     <*> m’
```

There are in total 8 of those errors I'm getting in the console.

I'd appreciate any help I can get here. I apologize if this post is a little lengthy and full of bad code.

EDIT: It turns out I've fixed my problem. Thanks to both [jonathan-portorreal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6682929/jonathan-portorreal) and [epsilonhalbe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630160/epsilonhalbe) I looked at my types again and also checked out the Lens package for some ideas. I ended up using a `do` block in my `FromJSON GameResult` instance but I was still having type problems because it turns out I was using `w` and `l` as certain field names in the `GameResult`ADT and outside of it.

```
instance FromJSON GameResult where
  parseJSON arr = do 
  [a,b,c,d,...,l,...,w,x,y,z] <- parseJSON arr
  team_ID   <- a
  game_ID   <- b
  game_date <- c
  matchup   <- d
  wl        <- e
  w         <- f
  l         <- g
  ...
            <- l
            ...
            <- w
```

I'll definitely clean this up though, probably will utilize the Lens package once I get more familiar with the basics.

Comment: based on this error it looks like `l :: Int` in your data constructor for `GameResult` should be of type `l :: Float` ; try lining up those types.

Comment: Working with huge datatypes like you do I'd recommend using `RecordWildCards` or some form of lenses if you have nested structures

Comment: I appreciate the help guys.

@JonathanPortorreal I tried to change the types in `GameResult` according to what the error messages were telling me, but it appears that it's telling me to change all my record fields to have type Int which won't match the array in the JSON. It'll also give me the error message:
`No instance for (FromJSON (Parser Int)) arising from a use of ‘parseJSON’` (referencing the line with `[...x,y,z] <- parseJSON arr`)  

@epsilonhalbe I'll look into lenses right now.  

Thanks again!

Comment: you could also convert the array into an object and then parse the object as a GameResult.

Comment: Thanks again @JonathanPortorreal I think I'll start refactoring it that way to clean it up.